# QQ, can I find the limit to that sequence with 3 sequence theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

As in the title - if it can be done that way, I will manage to get the right answer myself.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$? Please add more details.

Comment: Yeah, I will edit the title

Comment: I have figured out the answer. If you are willing to add some of your work, I will write an answer. It is better to show your attempts as well while posting a question.

Comment: Sure, just give me some time

Comment: I don't know, I mean I thought it may be a 3 sequence theorem, but now I can't find anything smaller (bigger would be without 1/2n). I think that induction is not the answer since I don't even know if there is any limit to that expression. It is pretty similar to $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n \to e$ but that 2 makes everything a bit complicated.

Comment: Oh! I got an idea, a 3 sequence theorem with -1?

Comment: Honestly my answer doesn't involve squeeze theorem since I can't figure out a solution using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{3^n-\left(2+\frac{1}n\right)^n}\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}3\sqrt[n]{1-\left(\frac{2}3+\frac{1}{3n}\right)^n}\\
&= 3\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{1-\left(\frac{2}3+\frac{1}{3n}\right)^n}\end{align}$$

Now,  $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln\left(\sqrt[n]{1-\left(\frac{2}3+\frac{1}{3n}\right)^n}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln\left[1-\left(\frac{2}3+\frac{1}{3n}\right)^n\right]}n$$
and note that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{2}3+\dfrac{1}{3n}\right)^n=0$. Therefore $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln\left(\sqrt[n]{1-\left(\frac{2}3+\frac{1}{3n}\right)^n}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln\left[1-\left(\frac{2}3+\frac{1}{3n}\right)^n\right]}n=\frac{\ln1}\infty=0$$
Therefore $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{1-\left(\frac{2}3+\frac{1}{3n}\right)^n}=e^0=1$$ Now we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=3\cdot1=3$$

Comment: Ok, but what do we do with that ln next? I mean you just added ln like it's nothing.

Comment: I mean before "Now," and after "Now," those are 2 different expressions

Comment: You can put everything into an index of e actually.

Comment: Sorry I edited my answer, does that help? I’m on a bus right now.

Comment: I take natural logarithm to evaluate an easier limit.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Is that a "common trick" by any measure?

Comment: I think so. It is taught in my high school and college.

Comment: And similarly, if I had a "problematic" power >1 then I could put it also into a log, right?

Comment: And why do you choose ln and not any other log by default? Any other would work the same in that case, but it is "safer" in limits to take ln, because it "covers more cases", right?

Comment: Yes you can. In that case, sometimes we will have to use L’Hospital Rule. It depends on the problem.

Comment: That’s also true. Another reason using ln is because when we use L’Hopital Rule, the derivative of $\ln x$ will be $\frac{1}x$. The logarithm will disappear.

Comment: Thank you! I don't think we will ever meet agin, but, man did you help me today :D

Comment: All those cases with induction and additionally ln... do you know any similar ways of dealing with limits that I should read about? I mean besides L’Hopital Rule, 3 sequence theorem, stolz theorem and $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n \to e$ thing?